# change background image and a:hover color of li

Tags: html, css

i  have this menu schema:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.asp">home</a></li>
        <li><a href="colecao.asp">coleção</a></li>
        <li><a href="tecnologia.asp">downloads</a></li>
        <li><a href="contato.asp">contato</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

My LI is `float:left` so, the itens are side by side. i want when i hover the `a:hover` my background LI, and a color changes.

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/56wUm/

If you hover only on `li`, the link dont work and the `a` dont change the color!

ty for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you still need help, I would suggest adding the padding to the a element in css rather than li. For example something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/MGRBS/2/

That way the link takes up the entire block space, Good luck. :D

Comment: This is the most correct way to do it, that way the actual link not only is hovered and clicked in the full area of the button, it also allows you to change the background on the same element.

Answer (score 1):

You should prefer using CSS Sprites to happen that. refer to these links

[vid link](http://www.from-the-couch.com/post.cfm/title/how-to-use-css-sprites)

http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/

Comment: yeah.. i think i need to use sprites... ty for help!

Answer (score 0):

To fix exactly what is going on, you need to change your a:hover rule slightly:

```
ul li:hover a { color: #fff }
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/56wUm/4/

However, in terms of usability, I think you'd be better off making the links take up all of the menu space, making a large target.

Comment: your solution is good, but when i hover the `li` we cant click. The link only work when we hover the `a` link

Answer (score 0):

You want to move some of that CSS from the A to the LI. The goal is to get the A to butt right up against the LI so there's no gap. You just want to use the LI's for their floating property, think of them like TDs in a TABLE. They should have no real style of their own.